# can I set the return url for ruby-openid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid, ruby-openid

I am using ruby-openid, can I change the return URL to something other than the default (current action)?

(Using rails 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `return_to` option:

http://rubydoc.info/github/openid/ruby-openid/OpenID/Consumer/CheckIDRequest#redirect_url-instance_method